# Why Process not printing output from cmd C#?

Tags: c#, printing, cmd, output

I'm tring to get the output from cmd, this command is working fine in the command line:
**if exist \qwerty (net use T: \querty ) else (echo false)**
But when I do that from c# doesn't work. Here the methods:

```
void mapDrive(String driveChar, string server,string user, string password){

    try
    {               
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;
        procStartInfo=new ProcessStartInfo();
        procStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(" if exist "+server+"(net use "+driveChar+": "+server+" /user:"+user+" "+password+" ) else (echo false)");
        //it should print 'false'
        proc.WaitForExit();     

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}

static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output from other process");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

static void cmd_Error(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error from other process");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

I took the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367557/how-to-parse-command-line-output-from-c)

EDIT:
Replaced 'Debug' FOR 'Console'.

Comment: You've said it doesnt work, but what about it isnt working...

Comment: The printing of the result ('false') is not working, either in the console either in the debug console

Comment: There are some known issues with the process input/output under debug.. Does it work under non debug conditions?

Comment: PS - it doesnt help that server+"(net has no space before the (

Comment: When I added the space before the ( I got a completely different result ....

Comment: @BugFinder  Tested with space, not working. In cmd I'm getting the same reult with or without space: 'false'. I think I'm missing something about how the hell works the console on SharpDevelop..

Comment: The added space also worked for me; check my last edit...

Comment: I notice that you are redirecting all of the standard, error, and input streams.  Check the docs for the `ProcessStartInfo` class as there is a potential deadlock problem that might prevent you from getting any output.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thx anyway. I asked the same topic again and got the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869169/process-class-not-printing-echo-output-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is a "command line application", you should use `Console.WriteLine`.

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5(v=vs.110).aspx

and also

[What's the difference between Console.WriteLine() vs Debug.WriteLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012822/whats-the-difference-between-console-writeline-vs-debug-writeline)

**Edit:** check the original code again... it is already using `Console.WriteLine`.

**Edit2:**
I tried this and worked for me:

```
static void mapDrive(String driveChar, string server,string user, string password){

    try
    {               
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;
        procStartInfo=new ProcessStartInfo();
        procStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(" if exist v: (echo true) else (echo false)");
        //it should print 'false'
        proc.WaitForExit();     

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}

static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output from other process");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

static void cmd_Error(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error from other process");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

**Edit3:** Ok, I think I've found it:
Try adding a space between '"+server+"' and  '(net'...:

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(" if exist "+server+" (net use "+driveChar+": "+server+" /user:"+user+" "+password+" ) else (echo false)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me as you would have expected when I made one change

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(" if exist "+server+" (net use "+driveChar+": "+server+" /user:"+user+" "+password+" ) else (echo false)");
```

If you put a space in front of ( it came back as expected

```
Output from other process
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Output from other process
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Output from other process

Output from other process
C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Conso
leApplication2\bin\Debug> if exist \\server01\share (net use Z: \\server01\share
 /user:. . ) else (echo false)
Output from other process
false
Output from other process
```

Comment: Copy paste from my code:    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(" if exist "+ **server+" (net ** use "+driveChar+": "+server+" /user:"+user+" "+password+" ) else (echo false)"); I have the space! :)  But no output from the command either in the Console, either in the Output Debug console. The ** means bold.

Comment: It has to be something about SharpDevelop console

Comment: Then take it up with them at a guess.

Comment: I've used SharpDevelop and worked for me... Why don't you test something like 'if exist \qwerty (echo true) else (echo false)'?

Comment: Neither works (it does on cmd). Do I have to do something in order to use the console In SharpDevelop? I added Console.Read(); at the end of  mapDrive() to block the console. But nothing shows up.

Comment: What do you mean with 'run a dir', the drive I want to map it's already a directory.

Comment: dir, dos command, lists files.. would give you output if the drive maps as your script doesnt show anything if your drive is mapped

Comment: How did you add the dir??

Comment: proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(" if exist "+server+" (dir t: ) else (echo false)"); Works in cmd. I will  delete the question today, it's extending so much. I will investigate by myself.