# Process class not printing echo output c#

Tags: c#, cmd, command, output

Due to the old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861150/why-process-not-printing-output-from-cmd-c) extended a lot, without working answers (but usefull), I would like to remodel it. The fact is in cmd all is working well, but not it c#. If the shared resource exist, the output of net use in c# is correct: 'Command completed' (in my case, in Spanish). 
But when the shared resource doesn't exist the echo 'false' works in cmd, but don't in c#, so I can't difference in the method what happened (user privilege or resource not found). In c# I tried:

```
String cmd = "....else (echo "+false+")";
String cmd = "....else (echo false)";
String cmd = "....else (echo 'false')";
```

No one works.
The method (modified from the old question):

```
void mapDrive(String driveChar, string server, string user, string password)
{

    try
    {

        String output;

        String cmd = "if exist " + server + " (net use " + driveChar + ": " + server + " /user:" + user + " " + password + " ) else (echo false)";
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c" + cmd);
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit(2000);
        proc.Close();

        StreamReader streamReader = proc.StandardOutput;
        output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine("CMD OUTPUT: " + output);

        if (output.Equals("false"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: couldn't found requested resource");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: you have no privileges");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `output` contain?

Comment: the output of the command I execute, if  **net use** is successfull: 'Command completed', if not it should be **false**  but never prints **false** :(

Comment: You are closing the process before trying to read from stdout. You should use `using` statements. If you change your exception handler to print `e.Message` you would have seen that. That's a good example of why catch-all exception handling can be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems in your code. First of all, you are closing the process before reading the output, so you should move your `proc.Close()` to the end of the method. The other problem is the output would contain a Newline, so change `if (output.Equals("false"))` to `if (output.Contains("false"))`