# How to send my notes to Output window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, output

Have a look at the picture. No matter where i put console.writeline, nothing is showing in output. Where could be a mistake? Is something wrong with my output editor or what?

[image]

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` writes to the *console*, not to the "Output" window. Use `Debug.WriteLine` instead.

Comment: How can i display console window instead of Output window? I have only found how to display output window.

Comment: Windows applications do not typically have console windows. Why do you need one?

Comment: Yeah. Console window is what you get in a CONSOLE application. One that opens a window when you start it (the console) and is typsically a command line app (though you CAN open the console window also in windows apps and just use it for stuff like debugging output=

Comment: I just asked because in java eclipse there is console window all the time. So you dont have be so astonished that i cannot find and without you have no idea what to think about it. Bye

Comment: Most likely, Eclipse just calls the "Console Window" what Visual Studio calls the "Output Window". As TomTom says, in Windows, a console is what you get when you run the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Debug.WriteLine` to write to the Output window as you want.

See also [What's the difference between Console.WriteLine() vs Debug.WriteLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012822/whats-the-difference-between-console-writeline-vs-debug-writeline)

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 questions instead of one: your main one and the comment "How can i display console window instead of Output window?"

1. You can write to VS output by using *Debug.WriteLine*. This requires System.Diagnostics namespace.
2. You can also run console window alongside with your windows application. Right click the project in Solution Explorer, select Properties, change Output Type to "Console Application" [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKaTu.png).